# How to Convert Abnormal Timestamp into datetime in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I'm creating a usage heatmap for some user analytics. The Y-axis will be day of the week and the X-axis will be hour of the day (24:00). I pulled the data from the API.(Note that this actually produces 6,000 rows of data)

IN:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("api.url")
data = response.json()
df=pd.DataFrame(data['Sessions'])
df.dtypes
print(df['StartTime'])
```

OUT:

```
0     2019-01-29T22:08:40
1     2019-01-29T22:08:02
2     2019-01-29T22:05:10
3     2019-01-29T21:34:30
4     2019-01-29T21:32:49
Name: StartTime, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

I would normally convert the object into pandas.dt and then split it into two columns:

IN:

```
df['StartTime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
df['Date'] = [d.date() for d in df['StartTime']]
df['Time'] = [d.time() for d in df['StartTime']]
```

OUT:

```
'     StartTime                Date           Time
0     2019-01-29T22:08:40      2019-01-29     22:08:40
1     2019-01-29T22:08:02      2019-01-29     22:08:02
2     2019-01-29T22:05:10      2019-01-29     22:05:10
3     2019-01-29T21:34:30      2019-01-29     21:34:30
4     2019-01-29T21:32:49      2019-01-29     21:32:49
```

This isn't working because of that funky "T" in the middle of my timestamp and possibly because of the datatype.

I need to remove the T so I can convert this to a standard datetime format, then I need to separate Date and Time into their own columns. BONUS: I'd like to bring only the hour into its own column. Instead of 22:08:02, it would just be 22.

Comment: Just `pd.to_datetime(df)` works.

Comment: That "T" isn't funky, it's part of the [ISO-8601 Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you for the info- I had no idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pandas timestamp:

```
>>> pd.Timestamp(‘2017-01-01T12’)
Timestamp(‘2017-01-01 12:00:00’)
```

So:

```
df['StartTime'] = df["StartTime"].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))

#now StartTime has the correct data type so you can access
# date and time methods as well as the hour

df['Date'] = df["StartTime"].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df['Time'] = df["StartTime"].apply(lambda x: x.time())
df['Hour'] = df["StartTime"].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

As mentioned by @coldspeed, calling pd.to_datetime() or pd.Timesatmp() would work just fine, just ommit the `format` arguments

Answer (score 0):

For parsing the timestamp [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) is fantastic. It can figure out a date from nearly any string format.

To get just the hour from a datetime object you can use *d.hour*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to format the timestamp. Pandas can recognize the datetime format as like '2019-01-29T21:34:30'.

IN:

```
import pandas as pd    
dt = '2019-01-29T21:34:30'    
pd.to_datetime(dt)
```

OUT:

```
Timestamp('2019-01-29 21:11:15')
```